# Query on concurrency with Spring authorization server token generation via client credentials grant type

Tags: spring-authorization-server

We are using spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server(v 1.1.1) and are able to generate jwt tokens but had a query with respect to performance and concurrency. Can someone point me to the document which shares how many concurrent requests(for token generation, introspection, etc.) can be handled concurrently with Spring authorization server and if there are any ways to optimize for production environments.

Thanks in advance